# Ubuntu 16.04 - How to assign unallocated space in /home partition using Gparted

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, filesystem, gparted

Recently I moved to Ubuntu from OSX. I've formatted my SSD Storage by the help of some tutorials on web. This is the allocation of space:
[image]

Initially I set 8GB of storage as `swap` but then I buy new memory and removed some space from `swap` partition. Now I want to use this unallocated space in my `/home` partition but I cant and not getting anything on web.

How Can I merge this *unallocated* memory with my `/home` partition?

Thanks In Advance
Ariful

Answer (score 0):

Backup you data from /home. unmount /home. destroy the partition sda6 and create a new one with the rest of space located on sda with fdisk.
I would recommend to use LVM (Logical Volume Manager) and not using native devices to create file systems on disks.Using LVM gives you the chance to expand file systems on the fly. shrinking needs most an unmount but it works dynamic on LVM Volumes. Ubuntu is giving you the choice during installation to use LVM for all file systems.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. I'll need time to apply the solution.. provably weekend. If it works, I'll come back for upvote.

Answer (score 0):

*Before performing this task, it's highly recommended that you backup your data. This task involves moving the start of a partition boundary, which is a high risk activity.*

- First you need to boot a LiveCD/USB because you need the partitions to be unmounted.
- Make sure your partitions are not mounted and then run Gparted.
- Right click your /home partition and select Resize/Move, and a Resize/Move window is displayed.

  - Click on the left-hand side of the partition and drag it as far to the left as possible.
  - Click Resize/Move to queue the operation.
  - Click on OK to acknowledge the move partition warning.
- Choose the Edit > Apply All Operations menu option, to apply the queued operations, to disk.
- Click on Apply to apply operations to disk.
- Click on Close to close the apply operations to disk window.
- Reboot to your operating system.

*Notice that there will be a gap, which can be up to about 8 MiB, due to having cylinder aligned and MiB aligned partitions on the same disk device.*

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. I'll need time to apply the solution.. provably weekend. If it works, I'll come back for upvote.