# Moving partition containing ubuntu to another partition on the same HDD

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

[image]

Currently I'm running low on memory of my ubuntu partition and unable to install additional packages.
I would like to copy `/dev/sda4` to `unallocated space` as shown in the image.

Or if possible copy only `/dev/sda5` to `unallocated space`.

Also I have windows installed in `/dev/sda2`

How would I do this ?

Comment: Try this solutions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/808061/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-assign-unallocated-space-in-home-partition-using-gparted), __please backup your data first__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how I did this.

**Step 1:** Live boot using USB.

**Step 2:** Extend `/dev/sda4` by merging this with `unallocated space` (101.85 GiB) above.

Step 2 results in moving the unallocated space into the extended partition i.e, just above `/dev/sda5` and just below `/dev/sda4`.

**Step 3:** Extend `/dev/sda5` by merging this with unallocated space above.

Done !

Comment: It may be move sda5 left and then expand right, unless gparted now does that as one step. Make sure not to interrupt any move as that totally corrupted all data, or why we always suggest good backups. Another alternative may be to create new ext4 partition and move /home. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving